# jQuery .load() fadeIn, fadeOut does not work in my remote server

Tags: jquery, local, fadein, fadeout

this might sound stupid but I have a problem I cant solve and i ve been cracking my head for a couple of days.

There is the code, it only works in localhost but not when i upload to a remote server. 
here is the page where im implementing it www.jvalladolid.com

how can i fixe it... I will appreciate your help :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#navigation li a').click(function () {

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' #MainContent';
    $('#MainContent').fadeOut('2000', loadContent);

    function loadContent() {
        $('#MainContent').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#MainContent').fadeIn('2000');
    }

    return false;

});
```

});

Comment: This line: `$('#MainContent').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent());` should actually be `$('#MainContent').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent);`, so that it actually calls the function once the AJAX load has completed. Also, if you have nothing for the data parameter, you can just skip it - you don't have to pass an empty string.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I modified that part but the result was that it didnt respond to the fadeIn timming setting... I really dont get it, when I run with visual studio everything seems to work perfect but in the remote server the effect is not the same... Does anyone have a clue?? :S - Im about to give up :/

Comment: I had this issue and realized I had jquery 1.7.1 on the server and was developing local with 1.11.0. Updating the server to 1.11.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in my browser (ff osx).